# If otherwise error " The <= operator can not be applied to operands of type "TextBox" and "int")

Tags: c#, winforms

I have just started programming and have an error that I can not fix.

> If otherwise error " The <= operator can not be applied to operands of
> type "TextBox" and "int").

```
private void bn_CocaCola_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int GetränkeWert = 2;

    if (tbh_GeldAs <= GetränkeWert)
    {
        tbh_GeldAs.Text = ("Endnehmen sie Ihr Getränk");
    }
    else
    {
        tbh_GeldAs >= GetränkeWert;
        tbh_GeldAs.Text = ("Sie müssen Geld einzahlen");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sidenote: It is considered best practice to write code in English. If possible, try to name your variables/Object in English.

Comment: @A-Tech No it's not.  The question on this site needs to be in English, but not their code.

Comment: @A-Tech tbh_MoneyAs is a textbox how should I convert it?

Comment: @LarsTech By no means required on SO, but in general you should try to keep your code in ENG. Especially if other developers might have to work on that code in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error messages are there to help us so try to look at what it is telling you. I looked at the error message in your post and it states that your expression...

`tbh_GeldAs <= GetränkeWert`

is a comparison of these types.

TextBox <= int.

So what is a textbox? It holds some text but you have to look at the `Textbox.Text` property.

`tbh_GeldAs.Text <= GetränkeWert`

But now this is comparing a string like "123" to an `int` and it still doesn't work!  You need to change that string to a number.

Try using the [convert class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=net-6.0). There you have the method `ToInt32` which can be called with a parameter (in your case `tbh_GeldAs.Text`). The method returns a variable with the same *value*, but now it has the numeric type `int`. Now you can use the greater/smaller operators.

Method call for your case:

`Convert.ToInt32(tbh_GeldAs.Text) <= GetränkeWert`

When converting variables like this, you don't need to save them into a variable. You can use the return value directly in your operation.

And while I hope this solves your problem, my *real* answer is to take the time to look at the error message and see what it's saying because they are usually quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use greater/smaller (</>) Operator on a string/text-variable <= contains such an operator.
tbh_GeldAs.text is a string/text-variable. Convert that to a numeric type and it should work.

Comment: I want to compare the value that is in the textbox with another one.